# How to change bibliography style from [1] to 1

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, amsrefs

I know that several people have already asked this question, but for some strange reason the suggestions are not working.

I have tried inserting:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
```

into the preamble of my `.tex` file, of the `.ltb` file, and of the style file that I am using, however nothing changes the references. This is and example of what has been tried:

```
\documentclass[noheadings]{uncthesis}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,slashed,amsfonts}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Alan Sokal~\cite{Sokal96} recommends Bourbaki's
text~\cite{Bourbaki70} for a gentle introduction to set theory.
\begin{thebibliography}{plain}
\bibselect{Bib}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The corresponding Bib.ltb would be:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\begin{document} 
\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
\bib{Bourbaki70}{book}{
title={Th\'eorie des ensembles},
author={Bourbaki, Nicolas},
date={1970},
publisher={Hermann},
address={Paris}
}
\bib{Sokal96}{article}{
title={Trangressing the boundaries},
subtitle={Toward a transformative hermeneutics of quantum gravity},
author={Sokal, Alan},
journal={Social Text},
volume={46/47},
date={1996},
pages={217--252}
}
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}
\end{document}
```

I have also tried inserting:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\BibLabel}{%
  \hfill
  \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{cite.\CurrentBib}\hyper@anchorend}%
\thebib.%
}
\makeatother
```

However, this yields the error message

```
2063: Undefined control sequence.
\BibLabel ->\hfill \Hy@raisedlink 
                              {\hyper@anchorstart {cite.\CurrentBib }\hy...
l.2063 \begin{thebibliography}{plain}
```

Are there any other suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Kathleen, [welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Redefining `\@biblabel` as you did in your code does change the list of references from `[n]` to `n.`. Perhaps you could include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, and also a fragment of your `.bib` file. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda No; if `amsrefs` is used, as is the case here, the mentioned redefinition of `\@biblabel` doesn't change the label formatting in the bibliography

Comment: @Kathleen I took the liberty of adding a MWE illustrating the problem, and the corresponding image; I hope it's OK.

Comment: And where is the file `uncthesis.cls` to be found?

Comment: Try loading the `amsrefs` package in your `.tex` file right before the redefinition: `\usepackage{amsrefs}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\BibLabel}{
  \hfill
  \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{cite.\CurrentBib}\hyper@anchorend}
\thebib.
}
\makeatother`.

Comment: If the above suggestion doesn't produce the desired result, we will need to see the document class that you are using (`uncthesis.cls`); since this is not a standard class, please provide a link to some site where we can download it.

Answer (score 4):

Since `amsrefs` is being used, a redefinition of `\BibLabel` is needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsrefs}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\BibLabel}{%
    \hfill
    \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{cite.\CurrentBib}\hyper@anchorend}%
    \thebib.%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Alan Sokal~\cite{Sokal96} recommends Bourbaki's
text~\cite{Bourbaki70} for a gentle introduction to set theory.
\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
\bib{Bourbaki70}{book}{
title={Th\'eorie des ensembles},
author={Bourbaki, Nicolas},
date={1970},
publisher={Hermann},
address={Paris}
}
\bib{Sokal96}{article}{
title={Trangressing the boundaries},
subtitle={Toward a transformative hermeneutics of quantum gravity},
author={Sokal, Alan},
journal={Social Text},
volume={46/47},
date={1996},
pages={217--252}
}
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for the record, here's the original definition:

```
\newcommand{\BibLabel}{%
    \hfill
    \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{cite.\CurrentBib}\hyper@anchorend}%
    [\thebib]%
}
```

A little explanation on why the redefinition of `\@biblabel` doesn't work with `amsrefs`: `\@biblabel` is a kernel's command and `amsrefs` doesn't use it to format the labels in the bibliography (amsrefs uses its own `\BibLabel` command); that's why redefining `\@biblabel` when the `amsrefs` package is used goes silently into oblivion (in particular, no error message will be produced) without any visible effect.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I think I need to provide some more information. This is what the tex file looks like:

\documentclass[noheadings]{uncthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,slashed,amsfonts}
 
\begin{document}  
Alan Sokal~\cite{Sokal96} recommends Bourbaki's
text~\cite{Bourbaki70} for a gentle introduction to set theory.

\begin{thebibliography}{plain}
\bibselect{Bib}
\end{thebibliography}
 
\end{document}  

And then I have a .ltb file that looks like:
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

Comment: @Kathleen does this mean that you tried my suggestion and it didn't work?

Comment: I did try it. I got an error message: Undefined control sequence. If I "Goto Error" it sends me to \begin{thebibliography}{plain}

Comment: @Kathleen what exactly is the *complete* error message? You didn't mention what is the undefined control sequence. Also, please, since code formatting in comments is a nightmare, edit your question and add the code there.